# ERROR: We requested an invalid product (In App purchase issue)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have recently launched my app in app store, my app has in app purchase feature.
I tested the in app purchase using sandbox mode as per standards and it worked fine.

The app got approved by Apple few days ago, but when i tried to do a real purchase in my app
it showed error like

```
ERROR: We requested an invalid product
```

This is pretty weird, i am sure the code configured is correct. 
I am testing the live in app purchase in the same device, i used to test the app before launch.

Any suggestion on this issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by removing the app and re installing it.